# Resetting a DIV in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Zurb's Orbit jQuery plugin to create a nested slider, that is, a slider within sliders...

It is almost done except for some bugs when applying the Orbit plugin to a second div. I think this would be solved by removing the Orbit plugin from the first div, and then applying it to the second.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#featured').orbit();
});
```

The above applies the Orbit plugin to the div... how would I remove it? Is there a simple jQuery method of doing so, or do I need to edit the Orbit plugin?

Comment: "a slider within sliders..." I'm patiently waiting for an Inception joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I put all the image URLs in an organized JSON file, and then dynamically created the DIVs for the slider. When the slider is not used, then I just nuke the DIV, and then create the next one.

Thanks for all the answers guys!!

Isaac

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Orbit, so this is a fairly wild guess. My understanding is that each jQuery plugin should expose its own method of removal / destruction, and I don't know if Orbit does (or what the method is if they do).

If there is no such method, you might try recreating the first `div` and appending the second back into it.

```
var newFirstDiv = $('<div>').append($('#featured'));
```

`newFirstDiv` will not have had the Orbit plugin applied to it, but it will also be void of any other contents that were in the original `div`, so keep that in mind (and put back whatever you need to).

You could also look at [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), but whatever orbit had done to the original would probably come along with it.

Comment: Clone is probably a good bet, I couldn't say how orbit works, but any jquery plugin should bind to an actual DOM element (since it doesn't really know anything about the selector that got whatever was passed to it). The only risk is that you will almost certainly have memory leaks by tossing an element with something that is actively bound to it if there are any closures used by it, which is likely.

Comment: @jamietre That's a good point about binding. I've looked at the Orbit js now, and (at a glance) it looks like it adds at least a class and a 1x1 element to the passed element. These changes would come along with clone, right?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like clone copies events (and children) as well. So you'd end up with all the junk possibly including some of the functionality, but likely confusing Orbit if it is using the original dom ref internally. Perhaps the right way to do this is to make a clone before binding orbit in the first place, and then revert to the original clone (or clone it again if this will happen more than once) in order to unbind.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(window).load(function() {
       $('#featured div').orbit();
    });
```